# Can I use numberPassword input type and still see the input?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

Can I use `numberPassword` as input type and still see the input?

My goal is to have a 0-9 keyboard with as few as possible other keys (that's why I prefered `numberPassword` over `phone`), but the user should still be able to see what he just typed.

This is what I have, but right now the passwords are hidden behind asterisks.

```
android:digits="1234567890"
android:inputType="numberPassword"
```

**Note:** I also tried `setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_PASSWORD)`, which made the input visible, but changed the keyboard from numbers-only to a regular keyboard. I need they keyboard to display numbers-only though.

Comment: You can toggle the asterisks using Java code, yes

Comment: can you tell me how? because the other methods didn't work for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This did the job:

```
uEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
uEditText.setTransformationMethod(null);
```

Comment: Setting PasswordTransformationMethod instance to transformationMethod like in other answers didn't work for me, but null worked just fine! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In Java, just do this:

```
edittext.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
```

If you wanted to hide the password later on, you would just do this:

```
editText.setTransformationMethod(HideReturnsTransformationMethod.getInstance());
```

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways you can solve this problem

1. You can use use TextInputEditText with TextInputLayout like below

   ```
   <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/etPasswordLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/login_spacing_bottom">

   <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
       android:id="@+id/etPassword"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:hint="@string/fragment_login_password_hint"
       android:inputType="textPassword"/>
   </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
   ```

With passwordToggleEnabled, you can toggle between asterisk and password values

2. You can use the Transformation class to toggle password asterisk and value like below

   ```
   edittextObject.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
   ```
3. You can create a custom keyboard with the values you want to display in your keyboard. You can see how to achieve this in this tutorial I wrote about [custom keyboard](https://inducesmile.com/android/how-to-create-an-android-custom-keyboard-application/)

Comment: Could you please explain #1? I am quite new to Android and haven't worked much with those layout files.